# Python Suds.Client Should it Close or Not

Tags: python, api, suds

I am using the `suds` package to make API request from one website. I wrote a function which opens up the `client` to the website and make request.

***I am wondering should I or how can I terminate the connection in the end of the function?***

I am wondering will the `client` be something like the `MySQLDb.connect` that actually opens up many many separate API connections that never close every time I call this function.

```
from suds.client import Client
import sys, re

def querysearch(reqPartNumber, reqMfg, lock):
    try:
        client = Client('http://app....')
        userInfo = {'id':.., 'password':...}
        apiResponse = client.service.getParts(...)
        ...
        print apiResponse
    except:
        ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOAP is still an HTTP request, which is stateless. Each request will start a whole new connection, re-auth, etc. Browsers kind of short circuit that with cookies, but SOAP doesn't. So, you don't need to close the connection, it's already closed by the time `suds` returns your data back to you.

Additionally, [looking at the latest source](http://svn.fedorahosted.org/svn/suds/trunk/suds/client.py), `Client()` doesn't define a `close` or `__exit__` method, so there's nothing you really have to do here.